# Unable to build docker image of a nodejs application

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I am trying to build a docker image but I keep getting [the error in this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUv7T.png) .
Pasted below is the whole error output I got. I literally do not know what is going on, and I need help. This is the link to the repo https://github.com/Royalboe/cd0354-monolith-to-microservices-exercises/tree/main/lesson-3-containers/exercises/base-images-exercise. Thanks.

```
#6 [3/8] RUN ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"   && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in     amd64) ARCH='x64';;     ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';;     s390x) ARCH='s390x';;     arm64) ARCH='arm64';;     armhf) ARCH='armv7l';;     i386) ARCH='x86';;     *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;;   esac   && set -ex   && for key in     94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5     FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E     71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1     DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D     C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8     B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9     77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A     8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600     4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C     A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762     B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C   ; do     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ;   done   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz"   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc"   && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc   && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c -   && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner   && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt   && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs   && node --version   && npm --version
#6 sha256:91975456fe09a84f2862151e2c312c669ef6da16a49ecfa8d15d509b38297d9f
#6 6.232 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5
#6 6.297 gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
#6 6.340 gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
#6 27.30 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 27.30 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5
#6 49.67 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 49.67 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5
#6 118.7 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
#6 118.7 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E
#6 130.1 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 130.1 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E
#6 140.3 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 140.3 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E
#6 179.7 gpg: key 09FE44734EB7990E: 5 signatures not checked due to missing keys
#6 179.7 gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
#6 179.7 gpg: key 09FE44734EB7990E: public key "Jeremiah Senkpiel <fishrock123@rocketmail.com>" imported
#6 180.8 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 180.8 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 180.8 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 180.8 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1
#6 190.1 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 190.1 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1
#6 199.4 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 199.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1
#6 257.8 gpg: key C97EC7A07EDE3FC1: 25 signatures not checked due to missing keys
#6 257.8 gpg: key C97EC7A07EDE3FC1: public key "keybase.io/jasnell <jasnell@keybase.io>" imported
#6 257.8 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 257.8 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 257.8 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 257.8 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D
#6 267.3 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 267.3 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D
#6 277.4 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 277.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D
#6 347.2 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
#6 347.2 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8
#6 359.4 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 359.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8
#6 371.9 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 371.9 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8
#6 475.6 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
#6 475.6 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9
#6 487.9 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 487.9 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9
#6 500.0 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 500.0 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9
#6 578.3 gpg: key B63B535A4C206CA9: 9 signatures not checked due to missing keys
#6 578.3 gpg: key B63B535A4C206CA9: public key "Evan Lucas <evanlucas@me.com>" imported
#6 578.4 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 578.4 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 578.4 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 578.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A
#6 588.6 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 588.6 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A
#6 598.7 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 598.7 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A
#6 672.7 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
#6 672.7 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600
#6 682.1 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 682.1 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600
#6 695.0 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 695.0 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600
#6 796.3 gpg: key 770F7A9A5AE15600: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
#6 796.3 gpg: key 770F7A9A5AE15600: public key "Micha▒l Zasso (Targos) <targos@protonmail.com>" imported
#6 796.3 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 796.3 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 796.3 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 796.3 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C
#6 806.6 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 806.6 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C
#6 816.2 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 816.2 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C
#6 898.0 gpg: key D7062848A1AB005C: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
#6 898.3 gpg: key D7062848A1AB005C: public key "Beth Griggs <bgriggs@redhat.com>" imported
#6 898.4 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 898.4 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 898.4 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 898.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762
#6 906.7 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 906.7 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762
#6 916.1 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 916.1 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762
#6 983.5 gpg: key F07496B3EB3C1762: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
#6 983.6 gpg: key F07496B3EB3C1762: public key "Ruben Bridgewater <ruben@bridgewater.de>" imported
#6 983.6 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 983.6 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 983.6 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 983.6 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C
#6 993.4 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 993.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C
#6 1003.4 gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
#6 1003.4 + gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C
#6 1071.7 gpg: key F13993A75599653C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
#6 1072.0 gpg: key F13993A75599653C: public key "Shelley Vohr (security is major key) <shelley.vohr@gmail.com>" imported
#6 1072.1 gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
#6 1072.1 gpg: Total number processed: 1
#6 1072.1 gpg:               imported: 1
#6 1072.1 + curl -fsSLO --compressed https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.12.0/node-v13.12.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
#6 1117.0 + curl -fsSLO --compressed https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.12.0/SHASUMS256.txt.asc
#6 1117.9 + gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc
#6 1118.1 gpg: Signature made Thu Mar 26 22:50:44 2020 UTC
#6 1118.1 gpg:                using RSA key 0EFFE1BCEFD9C84E3D098152933B01F40B5CA946
#6 1118.1 gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
#6 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"   && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in     amd64) ARCH='x64';;     ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';;     s390x) ARCH='s390x';;     arm64) ARCH='arm64';;     armhf) ARCH='armv7l';;     i386) ARCH='x86';;     *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;;   esac   && set -ex   && for key in     94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5     FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E     71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1     DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D     C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8     B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9     77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A     8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600     4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C     A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762     B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C   ; do     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ;   done   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz"   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc"   && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc   && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c -   && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner   && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt   && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs   && node --version   && npm --version]: exit code: 2
------
 > [3/8] RUN ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"   && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in     amd64) ARCH='x64';;     ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';;     s390x) ARCH='s390x';;     arm64) ARCH='arm64';;     armhf) ARCH='armv7l';;     i386) ARCH='x86';;     *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;;   esac   && set -ex   && for key in     94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5     FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E     71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1     DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D     C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8     B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9     77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A     8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600     4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C     A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762     B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C   ; do     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ;   done   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz"   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc"   && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc   && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c -   && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner   && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt   && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs   && node --version   && npm --version:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"   && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in     amd64) ARCH='x64';;     ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';;     s390x) ARCH='s390x';;     arm64) ARCH='arm64';;     armhf) ARCH='armv7l';;     i386) ARCH='x86';;     *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;;   esac   && set -ex   && for key in     94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5     FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E     71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1     DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D     C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8     B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9     77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A     8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600     4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C     A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762     B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C   ; do     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ;   done   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz"   && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc"   && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc   && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c -   && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner   && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt   && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs   && node --version   && npm --version]: exit code: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `gpg` cannot fetch the keys, maybe the servers are down, whatever. Try to replace the value of `--keyserver` specified in the Dockerfile with `hkps://keys.openpgp.org`.

I took the URL from here: https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-keys

Change this:

```
gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key"
```

to this:

```
gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys "$key"
```

and remove the following two commands that try using other two servers.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer? Sounds like it correctly identifies and resolves the issue